# Table formatting wrong mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting

I'm having a weird problem in mySQL. When I do a query on my data, the table sometimes goes like shown in the picture. The dayChange column on the right which looks empty, is actually appearing on the left and overwriting the first two columns. My question being, is anyone else having this problem, and is my data all still there, just not displaying properly? How do I get it to display properly?

mySQL with messed up table format:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running mysql through command line interfaces is always very buggy when it comes to displaying numerous columns. You can either try:

- running code through a proper SQL client.
- selecting two rows, one of which being the end column.

If data shows then it is present in the table.